# HTTP: Pattern to partially update a resource (that accepts empty strings)?

Tags: http, rest, post, resources

If there's a resource of type Foo with unique ID 36 at location:

```
http://example.com/foo/36
```

and a Foo contains several pieces of variable data (`var1`, `var2`, etc.), some of them strings;

What's the preferred pattern for updating a partial set of the resource's variables via HTTP (given that we may wish to set some to be empty strings)?

(The problem being that a form value of an empty string is [not considered "successful" by the W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) and is not required to be submitted by the browser. If the empty value is not sent, the server doesn't know that we wanted to set that variable to an empty string.)

I've thought of the following options:

1. `POST` to `http://example.com/foo/36` with a list of name/value pairs for variables that have a "successful" value, and an extra parameter, the value of which is a comma-separated list of values that we wish to set to be an empty string.
2. `PUT` to `http://example.com/foo/36/var1;var2;var3`, specifying the complete set of values that we want to update as part of the URI. Any specified name not received as a PUT argument will be set to an empty string.
3. Send separate `PUT` requests to each variable at `http://example.com/foo/36/var1`, `http://example.com/foo/36/var2`, etc. Expose every variable as a separate resource (very explicit, but involves lots of requests).

But none of these seem intuitive, elegant or standard to me.

Comment: Part of your question sounds like you're restricted to HTML forms. But, in that case, you're restricted to POST anyway. Right?

Comment: I don't want to restrict my applications to browsers so I prefer to implement other methods explicitly. To accommodate for browsers I use the non-official but common practice of "overloaded POST": allowing `POST` requests to submit an attribute named "method" with a value of "`PUT`", "`DELETE`", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mentioned approach are good ideas to bypass the parameter restriction you mentioned, but they are not that standard. Thinking that your api should to be client friendly, I would go the more common approach to use resource formats like JSON or XML:

- They are more "explicit" representations of your domain-data
- You can present null-values better (for instance either empty or non-existent XML-tag).

The browser could send the data by AJAX in JSON format.

for create you would sent complete data:

```
POST /foo
...
{"var1":"x","var2":2,"var3":"hello"}
```

for (partial) update:

```
PUT /foo/123
...
{"var1":"y","var2":null}
```

In partial update "var3" would be preserved.

For updates I prefer to always send complete data (not partial ones like above), because it eases mapping + implementation. But there are cases where partial updates are necessary.

Comment: This is interesting; I hadn't considered using JSON. But am I right in thinking that there's no way to send data like this from a browser form without using Javascript? I'm really trying to make my applications as accessible as possible to all types of client.

Comment: normal forms inside browser (i.e. non-js/ajax based) are sending mime-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1). this works fine for "normal" webapplications but it isn't really api-friendly format (see your examples). difficult... if you don't want to use javascript my advise would be to modularize your backend, so it is easier to share code between the browser-based HTTP endpoint and the "real" api. what kind of webapplication do you have? maybe http://www.sencha.com/products/js/ could be an option (api-backend is core concept).

Comment: After a lot of testing and deliberation I've decided to restrict non-javascript browsers to updating a whole resource at a time and allow `POST`ing partial resources for javascript and non-browser clients using JSON. Thanks for your nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to modify somewhat the PUT semantics so that only the sent value/pairs are updated in the resource: if the resource doesn't exist, create it with the info in the PUT request; if the resource exists, update only the passed name/value pairs.

I even think partial updates would be a nice addition to the rest architecture. Just use some HTTP header to indicate it.

Comment: but this doesn't allow me to set variables of the resource to empty strings. An empty string is not required to be sent by the browser (see the link in the question) so there's no way to ensure its inclusion in the name/value pairs.